# Can I use a multiple selector expression on the jQuery filter method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of anchor tags that I want to select. But if the href attribute of those links equals "#" or "" (an empty string) then I want to exclude them from the selection.

Currently I have the following which filters out the selection if the href **doesn't equal "#"**:

**Demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/dzrRS/2/

```
jQuery("a[href]").filter("[href!='#']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
 });
```

I have then tried altering this to the following in order to also filter out the selection if the href also doesn't equal "". **However this doesn't work.**

```
jQuery("a[href]").filter("[href!='#'], [href!='']").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
     });
```

In order to achieve my selection I have had to use the **filter method twice. e.g**.:

```
jQuery("a[href]").filter("[href!='#']").filter("[href!='']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
 });
```

**Do I really need to do this or can multiple selectors be used within the one filter method?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery("a[href]").filter("[href!='#'][href!='']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ for more information.

Comment: thanks, I kept finding myself at the Multiple Selector page, not the Multiple Attribute Selector page. I would've got away with it if it wasn't for those pesky commas!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be slightly more verbose, and potentially more easily understood, you could use:

```
jQuery('a[href]').filter(
    function(){
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        return (href.indexOf('#') > -1 && href.length);
    }).addClass('selected');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B8NDG/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).